Angular build command in gitlab runner is stuck
I have setup my gitlab runner to run with kubernetes pods. I am trying to build angular using gitlab runner using docker file. But looks like post switching to new runner I am seeing error like
INFO[0107] Running: [/bin/sh -c cd /app && node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --aot --configuration stage] 
Warning: Entry point '@clr/angular' contains deep imports into '/app/node_modules/@cds/core/icon', '/app/node_modules/@cds/core/icon/register'. This is probably not a problem, but may cause the compilation of entry points to be out of order.
error building image: error building stage: failed to execute command: waiting for process to exit: signal: killed
Compiling @angular/core : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling primeng/dom : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/animations : es2015 as esm2015
Compiling @angular/cdk/keycodes : es2015 as esm2015
Warning: Worker #3 exited unexpectedly (code: null | signal: SIGKILL).
  Current task: {entryPoint: primeng/dom, formatProperty: es2015, processDts: Yes}
  Current phase: compiling
Compiling @angular/compiler/testing : es2015 as esm2015
Warning: Worker #2 exited unexpectedly (code: null | signal: SIGKILL).
  Current task: -
  Current phase: -
Warning: Worker #1 exited unexpectedly (code: null | signal: SIGKILL).
  Current task: {entryPoint: @angular/core, formatProperty: es2015, processDts: Yes}
  Current phase: compiling

I am unable to figure out the issue in this. Not sure if it's Angular issue or runner issue.

Maybe you can focus on resolving the warning :

This was always there for me. But never caused an issue.

Try to increase the memory before the build, some times the process is killed when it does not have enough memory. export NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=2048 && npm run build

@OscarLudick - Already doing it. No luck
ENV NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"
RUN cd /app && node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --aot --configuration stage

Check this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36278
